# Maven project site directory

Tags: java, maven, collaboration, sourceforge

Does anyone know whether there is some sort of central registry for maven sites?

My situation is: My company has a LOT of development teams, each developing some product. Most of these products are managed by maven. It's easy to generate a site for each project using site plugin. However, we would like to have a central point where we could navigate through all the projects. In other words, we would like a private sourceforge maybe using the individual project sites.

Any advice on that?

Comment: Could you please share detailed answer how you solved that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the latest version of the Nexus repository server. The open source as well as the professional version now (as of 2.0.0) have the site plugin available. It is exactly designed for your use case of publishing a Maven site to a central server.

Read more about it in the [free book about Nexus](http://sonatype.com/index.php/Support/Books/Repository-Management-with-Nexus) or even attend a training or watch the webinar about the latest release.